# Bind two related DataSets to two DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a problem binding a DataSet with two tables related, I have been searching for many time. I am not sure how to do this with a WPF DataGrid (it seems to be different than with a WinForms DataGrid).

I am using MVVM pattern and have my DataContext associated with my DataSet, one grid is bound on `ItemsSourceProperty` to one of the tables. I am wondering how you select one item in `dataGrid1` and automatically bind the related rows to `dataGrid2`.

Comment: Could you give an example of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is to know your Relation Name. let us assume the tables are **Student** and **Classes** and the relation name is: **FK_Student_Classes**, then your binding looks like this:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grdStudents" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataSet.Student}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=grdStudents, Path=SelectedItem.FK_Student_Classes}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

when ever you select a row in the student grid you will see all related rows for in your classes grid.

Comment: That is really what I am trying to do !!. Thanks, I am going to try know